# Dictionary Keys and Values to a Select List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
Dictionary<string,string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();    
  dict.add("a1", "Car");
  dict.add("a2", "Van");
  dict.add("a3", "Bus");
```

---

```
SelectList SelectList = new SelectList((IEnumerable)mylist, "ID", "Name", selectedValue);
```

In above code I have put a list `mylist` to a `SelectList`. `ID` and `Name` are two properties of that particular object `list(mylist)`.

Likewise I need to add the Dictionary to the `SelectList.`

---

Need to add the key of the dictionary to the `data Value` parameter -(`ID` position of above example)
Need to add the value of the dictionary to the `data text` parameter -(`Name` position of the above example)

So please tell me a way to create a select list using this dictionary keys and values without creating a new class.

Answer (score 43):

You could try:

```
SelectList SelectList = new SelectList((IEnumerable)dict, "Key", "Value", selectedValue);
```

`Dictionary<string, string>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`, and `KeyValuePair` gives you the `Key` and `Value` properties.

Be aware, however, that the order of items returned by enumerating a `Dictionary<string,string>` is not guaranteed.  If you want a guaranteed order, you can do something like:

```
SelectList SelectList = new SelectList(dict.OrderBy(x => x.Value), "Key", "Value", selectedValue);
```

Comment: Short, direct and justified. Excelent answer!

Answer (score 27):

All you really need to do is pass the dictionary as a parameter and use the overload:

```
public SelectList(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField);
```

Example:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
   {"a1", "Car"}, 
   {"a2", "Van"}, 
   {"a3", "Bus"}
};

var selectList = new SelectList(dictionary, "Key", "Value");
```

I know the post is a bit old but I came here to find the answer and came to this conclusion based on the previously given answers.

Answer (score 3):

You could construct a list of SelectListItem objects from the Dictionary and then create a SelectList from that.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
   {"a1", "Car"}, 
   {"a2", "Van"}, 
   {"a3", "Bus"}
};

var myListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

myListItems.AddRange(dict.Select(keyValuePair => new SelectListItem()
{
    Value = keyValuePair.Key, 
    Text = keyValuePair.Value
}));

var myList = new SelectList(myListItems);
```

Answer (score 3):

I like to write it like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Delimiter,
                                         new Dictionary<string, string>
                                         {
                                             {",", ", (Comma)"},
                                             { ";", "; (Semicolon)"}
                                         }.Select(x => new SelectListItem {Value = x.Key, Text = x.Value}))
```

Because this way, you don't have to rely on the strings `"Key"` and `"Value"`.

Answer (score 1):

I used this for a list of SelectListItem and it works fine for select tag and dropdown

```
dict.OrderBy(x => x.Value).Select(r => new SelectListItem(r.Key, r.Value));
```

Comment: Be careful with the order of key and value in the SelectListItem constructor. The display text comes first, and the "value" sent from the SelectList comes second. Coming from a Dictionary, you probably want "r.Key" to be the SelectList value, while "r.Value" is the display text. I.e., `r => new SelectListItem(r.Value, r.Key)`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SelectList SelectList = new SelectList((IEnumerable)mylist, "Key", "Value", selectedValue);
```

---