# Select2 multiple select passing key,value pairs on postback

Tags: asp.net

I am using Select2 Tags using a dropdown as well as a direct input and have the following code in my View:

```
<select id="lessonTags" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" style="width:100%" name="SelectedTags">
@foreach (var lesson in Model.Lessons)
{
<option value="@lesson.Id">@lesson.Title</option>
}
```

In my viewmodel I just created a temp variable string[] SelectedTags which gives me the string of what was selected via the dropdown as well as anything that was typed in that was not in my original options.

So currently I have to loop through my data and match to see if the SelectedTags array has a match on my db, if it does then I can use that Id in my model, if it doesn't exist then I have to Create that lesson in my DB.

I find this to be extra processing, it would be nice if I can just pass say a key, value pair of ID/Lesson.Title and anything that I typed wouldn't have an ID so I can easily identify what needs to be created on the DB.

Is there a way to pass the key/value pair via the name tag?

EDIT: Currently whats getting returned is the lesson.Id if its in the list or the actual text if its not - the issue with this is if the user types in a number, i can't discern between an Id and the users number...hence I am thinking I need to somehow flag a new piece of data.

Comment: How about using `selectList` : [Dictionary Keys and Values to a Select List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307443/dictionary-keys-and-values-to-a-select-list)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by adding Select List please? How would I use this with the select/option control from select2?